# 404 error when viewing details of a poll in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working through the Django tutorial anf. For some reason, if I try to manually type in the URL like so: `http://localhost:8000/polls/1/` I can view the poll (in this case the id of the poll is 1). But if I'm at the index of all the polls, which would be the URL: `http://localhost:8000/polls` and I try to click on one of the polls, it takes me to an error page with the following:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
^polls/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^polls/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^polls/ ^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/
The current URL, polls/{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id % }, didn't match any of these.
```

Here's my `polls/urls` file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    )
```

And my mysite/urls file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And my template file:

```
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id % }">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

I've seen similar questions but it doesn't seem that they apply to me. Why does it work when I type in the URL but not when I *click* on the link that should take me to the same place?

Comment: Try `{% url polls:detail poll.id % }` (without quotes).

Comment: simply look at the code source of the index of all polls, the links are probably bads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have space between % and }, try this

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">
```

Comment: I actually had it without the space originally, then changed it afterwards to have the space. Since that's how it is in the tutorial, I'm still having the same issue. Do you know why the parameter for `name` is in square brackets? Like `[name='index']`, it's not that way in my `urls.py` code